# Can I get the bindings output that Helm shows into another buffer?

Tags: helm

I know that I can bring up a Helm buffer which shows available bindings. But I would like to do some scripting around available keybindings and commands. Is there a way to dump that output to a regular buffer rather than to Helm?

Comment: Are you just looking for `C-h b` ? (which *is* `describe-bindings`, so I'm a bit confused by your question, but maybe helm hijacks that binding?  Compare with `emacs -Q`).

Comment: @phils LIke I said, I want to do some scripting around available keybindings (namely put them into an Anki flash card deck) in order to do that I need a list of *all* the keybindings and commands. The minibuffer does have that, but isn't something I can just dump to a file to work with.

Comment: That's what `describe-bindings` does - it creates a buffer listing all the available key bindings. You can save that buffer to a file like you would any other buffer.

Comment: @Tyler when I run `describe-bindings` it opens up a buffer named HELM Descbinds - I can't do anything but type a pattern to filter it or dismiss it.

Comment: `helm-descbinds`  overrides the default version of `describe-bindings`. Disable `helm-descbinds` and you should get the default version again